# Value of my variables won't update on my script

Tags: roblox

i am making a simulator map when you have to refill your backpack

to refill my backpack i copy the value of the capacity of my backpack but if i change the value of the capacity of backpack variable, it won't refresh the value and give the first value.

```
local db = false

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) then
        if not db then
            db =true
            local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
            
            plr.data.Mail.Value = 0
            plr.data.Mail.Value = plr.data.Backpack.Value
            script.Parent.Sound:Play()
            
            wait(1)
            db = false
        end
    end
end)
```

thank you if you can help me !

Comment: Please post your code here with proper formatting. Pictures of code are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. plr.data.Backpack is not a variable, it is an object, you could name a variable an item you gave a value inside your script, such as "local db = false", this is a variable.
2. There is few ways of changing value in roblox, if you changed a value from your client while testing (debuging) changes won't appear, you would need to switch to server-side of current debug session in your roblox studio or use a server console to execute the code.

Try to debug by writing this into your event function somewhere in the end

```
local val = 243453543 --replace with some value
plr.data.Backpack.Value = val
```

if everything is correct you should see the value of 'val' variable as a value of plr.data.Backpack, you can check it in your explorer, there is also no needs to write `plr.data.Mail.Value = 0` row because you are changing the value again without any other methods, values doesn't need to be cleared.

So in the end you should have:

```
local db = false

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) then
        if not db then
            db =true
            local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
            
            
            plr.data.Mail.Value = plr.data.Backpack.Value
            script.Parent.Sound:Play()
            
            wait(1)
            local val = 243453543
            plr.data.Backpack.Value = val

            db = false
        end
    end
end)
```

Also check plr.data.Backpack.className is "NumberValue" in explorer.